# How to say that I have attended big competitions and get no result?

Tags: resume

In the Activities field, I decide to write down two volunteer jobs and two competitions I have attended. For the volunteer jobs, it's easier to say because I don't lose or win anything; the result represents what I have done. However, for the competitions, although I have worked hard to be a member of the team of my university to compete with other team, I still don't have any prize or medal. Being a member is very honor, and I think I definitely need to write it down to my CV, but I don't know how to tell it in detail. If I don't, I think it will not proportional to the volunteer jobs part since I can tell easily what I got.

What should I do?

---

The competitions were about chess and physics. The teams didn't have leaders, they just had managers which were the teachers. That means there was no project to make, individual working. And what should I say about specific skills? Good at chess and physics or can cope with pressure? That's too obvious.

Comment: You would want to say "competed in" rather than "attended". And you can say that whether you won or not. However, unless chess or physics are directly related to the jobs you're looking for, I'm not sure this would do much but act as a starting point for conversation.

Comment: I apply for a master scholarship so I think these activities are quite important. However I also want to ask for general case. I think in any circumstance, they will give me an extra point in the HR'S eyes.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. I'd be impressed by this as a hobby, but I don't know that it would have any effect on my decision to interview/hire you. But I don't pretend to understand the HR screening process.

Comment: In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bu3pYKKqRS8), the narrator tells that she got a job because she studied physics :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A CV / Resume is an advert for yourself.  You don't see a chocolate bar advertising itself as "Entered in the 2013 Best Candy Bar Awards", do you?

So, how do you turn this lack of award into a net positive? Something recruiters will find interesting?

Firstly - is any of the project work still available? Can you point to a website? Or any tangible results?

Secondly - working well as a team member is a valuable skill.  Can you say "lead a team of X people to create a Y in only Z days"?

Thirdly - think of relevance.  If you're applying to be a fry-cook, do I care that you took 5th place in a Chess competition? No.  It may be important to *you* but it's not *relevant* to your job application.

Finally - think about what you want to show the recruiter. Team leadership? Specific skills? Ability to cope under pressure?  Highlight those aspects carefully. They could be what a recruiter is looking for.

Comment: I like the idea of Candy Bar Awards. Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question to give more information. Please come and see.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Keep your CV relevant. There's nothing wrong with "obvious" achievements as long as you can adequately demonstrate them.

Comment: relevant, got it. I think chess will make an extra point if you apply for labors which need to use brain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ooker also depending on the nature of work having a sound logical mind that can look ahead a fair distance than be stuck in "now" can be a very valuable trait. (basically the way I look at it, is put it there if it makes sense, otherwise try to find something better to point out your capabilities)

Answer (score 4):

Coming at this from a slightly different angle than [Terence Eden's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/35149/168).

In general the best method for including competition participation will depend on the field. Some fields it only counts if you win(in which case 'Candy Bar Award' is an excellent example) but in other fields even competing brings with it a certain level of prestige.

Consider an Olympic level athlete - sure it'd be nice to put "Brought home the gold in the 2020 Olympic keyboard surfing competition" but the reality is that if you are good enough to compete in the Olympics then you have already 'won' prestige. A couple more realistic examples would be - I am a computer scientist. I competed in an Artificial Intelligence challenge. There were only 15 other competitors - I 'won' the right to compete in a very tough competition even though I did not 'WIN' the competition. I would definitely put that I competed. If you are a chef and are invited to compete in the Bocuse d'Or it is absolutely worth it to mention the participation. In these fields(and others) there are competition where the participation itself is prestigious, let alone winning.

All of this being said it's all a matter of context isn't it? In general if it is a prestigious competition OR related to the field in which you are applying I would include your participation. Additionally you should consider ways in which you can 'spin' the experience into pluses for your job (under pressure, strategic, group planning, etc) though, personally, I would save such explanations for both the cover letter and the interview rather than the resume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in short, do you suggest that I should only tell that I have attended the competition in the CV in one line and explain them in detail in the cover letter?

Comment: If the competition is applicable to the job OR you are otherwise lacking in expeience/things to talk about then I would include more details in the coverletter/interview. In the US a resume should include mainly keywords and concepts that will catch HR's eyes and move you to the next step.